# FAIL - Application at context path /Hello could not be started

Tags: deployment, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm trying to deploy new web application in Tomcat 6.0, but whenever I click on start button, I repeatedly getting  **FAIL - Application at context path /Hello could not be started**. Other deployed application running fine, whenever I click on start button. But why not this application?

**web-xml:**

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>j_security_check</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>EmailHander</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<form-login-config>
<form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
<form-error-page>/fail_login.html</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
</login-config>
<web-app>
```

This is what Exception I'm getting in catalina log file:

```
Jan 23, 2010 6:49:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/Hello/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1644)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4339)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1249)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:612)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

What is the reason of that error in web-xml file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your `web.xml` ends with `<web-app>`, but must end with `</web-app>`

Which by the way is almost *literally* what the exception tells you.

Answer (score 7):

You need to close the XML with `</web-app>`, not with `<web-app>`.

Answer (score 2):

Is `EmailHandler` really the full name of your servlet class, i.e. it's not in a package like `com.something.EmailHandler`? It has to be fully-qualified in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, was missing a slash in servlet url in web.xml

replace

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsonservice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>jsonservice</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

with

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsonservice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsonservice</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

check web.xml file maybe servletContextlistener not doing well .
in my case i added servletContextlistener and let him an empty and gave me the same error, i tried to delete it from project files but it still  in web.xml file .finally i delete it from the web.xml and save the file . run the project and it stated successfully

Answer (score 0):

**1st Reason** could be the ending tag of your application's web.xml file which could not have been closed properly.

web.xml might be ending with `<web-app>`, but must end with `</web-app>`

**2nd Reason** which worked in my case could be the lib folder of your tomcat must contain the supporting jar file of your database.

`ojdbc` on case of Oracle or `sqljdbc` in case of SqlServer

Answer (score 0):

The java version used by Tomcat must be correct. The version that is 8.5 uses 1.8 java.